# Does every light ray have a normal?

Tags: visible-light

I am currently learning about light rays and how we see things and I have recently learnt about the normal, an imaginary line.

I was wondering if every light ray has a normal?

Thanks.

Comment: Given that ray optics is a simplified model of light propagation, this seems more a question of geometry than physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *light ray* is a mathematical construct.  It helps us visualize how light travels in a specific direction.  So, let's start with accepting that the light you're thinking about is beam traveling in a straight line.

A *normal* is often thought of a the direction that is perpendicular to a plane.  So, one way to think of applying the word "normal" to light is to consider the light to be propagating in a specific direction and that the normal is parallel to that direction.  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave)  The *plane* is thus perpendicular to this normal.  It is an infinite sheet that represents the constant phase of the electromagnetic wave that light represents.

With this description in mind, *not* every field of light is a *plane-wave* and thus not all light propagation can be described with a normal.

However, the normal is still a useful concept.  A converging (focusing) wavefront is a *spherical-wave*.  (see http://www.kshitij-iitjee.com/spherical-and-plane-waves)  Over a very small area of that sphere it has a normal that points towards the center of the sphere.  So the normal still has utility for this case.

There are cases where a simple normal is insufficient.  What if I took two lasers and crossed them like an "X".  Where they cross, the two beams overlap.  At this point, there are two plane waves traveling in different directions.  This **cannot** be described using a normal.  This occurs in optical systems that are aberrated.  The *caustic* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_%28optics%29 ) is a ray bundle where light rays cross over themselves in a complex fashion.

So, I think the answer to the question is not every field of light can be described with a normal.